# uitableview automatic dimension returning error on console while looks ok on simulator

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am having issues with `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` for a tableview with two prototype cells.

First thing I am not sure I am doing right is to define on `viewdidload` the following code. As I have two prototype cells, not sure how they both will make use of this single code or if this the cause of my problem.

```
myTableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
myTableView.estimatedRowHeight = 120.0
```

One of the prototype cells work fine and return no errors. The on that has no image and the which the height is 120px.

The other prototype cell, has an image to it and screenshots are bellow, returns the error bellow.

If I remove all the vertical constraints between the votes, image and text the error is gone, but the cell goes crazy. If i bring these constraints back, the cell looks fine, but I get the errors in the console.

> Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.     Probably at least one
>   of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try
>   this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you
>   don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or
>   constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing
>   NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer
>   to the documentation for the UIView property
>   translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints)

[image]
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try removing the auto-resizing check.

Answer (score 0):

No need to create two cells, as a dynamic cell automatically changes its height according to its content. If you assign an image it will adjust according to the image size, otherwise make it nil and see the magic of dynamic cells.

Don't forget to double check your constraints as dynamic cells work with autolayout constraints. Every View in your content view should have a top to bottom constraint so it pushes its content view according to the content.